# upload file in code igniter version 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

actually, if Edit button is click and i do not change any fields and submit the form at the time creating again one more same name image and saving database also
so how will resolve this issue .help me.

below the my code:

```
$foldername =$_POST['image_exists'];
//echo $foldername;die;
$old = umask();
        clearstatcache();
if (! file_exists($foldername))
{
    //echo "hdhdhdh";die;
    $folderName = $_POST['event_name'].time();
    $pathToUpload = 'images/events/' . $folderName;
    //$create = mkdir($pathToUpload, 0777,true);
    // chmod($pathToUpload,0755,true);
    //if (! $create)
    //return;
}
else{
    //$folderName = $_POST['event_name'].time();
    //$pathToUpload = 'images/events/' . $folderName;
       echo $foldername."already exits";
}
umask($old);
$config['upload_path'] = $pathToUpload;
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '9999';
$cofig['overwrite'] = 1;
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if(isset($_POST['image_exists']) && $_POST['image_exists'] != '')
$temp_image = $_POST['image_exists'];
//print_r($temp_image);die;
if(isset($_FILES['event_image']['name'])  && $_FILES['event_image']['name'] != "")
{
  if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('event_image'))
  {
    // $data = $this->upload->data();
    echo "failed";
    // echo 
  }
  else
  {
    $data = $this->upload->data();
    $eventimage = $data['file_name'];
    //echo $eventimage;die; 
  }
}
else
{
  $eventimage = $temp_image;
}

$event_name = ucwords(strtolower($this->input->post('event_name')));
$event_image = $folderName.'/'.$eventimage;
```

Comment: so your issue in uploading your image ? or in duplicating it in database? if though , you will need to check so if only changes happens then update your database;

Comment: I'd suggest don't create folders by event names rather use event ids. Create a folder events in uploads and then keep creating folders by event ids

Answer (score 1):

Alright Mr. Raja. I have Simulated your entire problem on my machine. May I suggest a little improvements in your code structure.

**Step-1 . Database**

[image]

Let's assume we have above ERD to implement with one table for events and other for event images. Let's put some sample data in it, create a view and render it in tabular format

[image]

**Step-2. Image Upload**

Clicked on the Images tab on First event. We got the form and you can see there is only one folder in uploads which is event. Lets upload some images

[image]

We tried to upload the images, two things happened success message and folder creation

[image]

**Step-3. Delete Image**

I have also placed a delete link here which not only deletes the image from the database but also delete from the directory. lets try that, I will delete one image

[image]

Here we go, the image is delete from the directory too.

**Step-4. How it Works**

I won't go into markup details of view, its standard Bootstrap, I am sure you can make them as per your designs. Lets talk about Controller first

***List Events***

```
public function events()
{
    $data['events']=$this->Events_model->getEvents();
    $this->load->view('events',$data);
}
```

That's it. Yes you must be wondering about getEvents Function in Event Model, lets see that.

```
public function getEvents()
{
    return $this->db->get('events')->result_array();
}
```

***Event Images Page***

Controller function

```
public function event_images()
{
    $eventId=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $data['event']=$this->Events_model->getEventById($eventId);
    $data['images']=$this->Events_model->getEventImages($eventId);
    $this->load->view('event_images',$data);
}
```

Two Model function in it, getEventById which gets data for current event and getEventImages to show in case there are already event images in database.

Model Functions

```
public function getEventById($id)
{
    $st=$this->db->SELECT('*')->from('events')->WHERE('id',$id)->get()->result_array();
    return $st[0];
}

public function getEventImages($id)
{
    $st=$this->db->SELECT('*')->from('event_images')->WHERE('event_id',$id)->get()->result_array();
    if(!empty($st))
    {
        return $st;
    }
    else
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

***Upload Image***

The Form is calling do_upload function in the controller to upload image, I am using codeigniter upload library but before that I am making sure the path / directory exist. Following is the form opening line which will give you idea what is happening

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url().'Test/do_upload/'.$this->uri->segment(3)?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I am sending the event id to do_upload function in URL

Controller Function

```
public function do_upload()
{
    $eventId=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $path='uploads/events/'.$eventId;
    if(!is_dir($path))
    {
        mkdir($path);
    }

    $config['upload_path']          = './'.$path;
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 500;
    $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    $config['max_height']           = 768;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile1'))
    {
        $data['errors'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $data['event']=$this->Events_model->getEventById($eventId);
        $data['images']=$this->Events_model->getEventImages($eventId);
        $this->load->view('event_images',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file_name=$upload_data['file_name'];
        $this->Events_model->updateEventImage($file_name,$eventId);
        $data['success']='Congratulations! Image Updated Successfully';
        $data['event']=$this->Events_model->getEventById($eventId);
        $data['images']=$this->Events_model->getEventImages($eventId);
        $this->load->view('event_images',$data);
    }
}
```

***Delete Image***

Controller Function

```
public function DelImage()
{
    $eventId=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $imageId=$this->uri->segment(4);
    $this->Events_model->delImage($imageId);
    redirect(base_url().'Test/event_images/'.$eventId);
    // OR redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

Model Function

```
public function delImage($id)
{
    $image=$this->db->select('*')->from('event_images')->WHERE('id',$id)->get()->row();
    $path='uploads/events/'.$image->event_id.'/'.$image->image;
    unlink($path);
    $this->db->query('DELETE from event_images WHERE id='.$id);
}
```